# playbook giving syntax error

Tags: debian, ansible

i am running this playbook, but its failing at last task.
running this from ubuntu host,,

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   tasks:
   - name: Copy certificate files.
     copy:
        src: "{{ item.src }}"
        dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0644
     with_items:
     -  {  src: "/registry_certs/domain.crt", dest: "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt" }

   - command: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
   - command: sudo update-ca-certificates

   - name:  "just force systemd to reread configs (2.4 and above)"
     systemd:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       state: started
       daemon_reload: yes
     with_items:
     - docker
     - kubelet
```

error

```
ubuntu@kops:/etc/ansible$ sudo ansible-playbook certificate_new.yml -l aws  --syntax-check
ERROR! no action detected in task

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/certificate_new.yml': line 18, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   - name:  "just force systemd to reread configs (2.4 and above)"
     ^ here
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with Unix & Linux and it already has [an answer (Reason #1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159200/2947502) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per `Ansible` syntax, after `tasks:`, you need to indent `- name:` and the other tasks bellow, one space more as in:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: Copy certificate files.
```

Comment: This is blatantly wrong. YAML does not require this and by no means it is a reason for the error in the question.

Comment: well then whats the solution fot this balantly wrong error,,bcoz its the error which is being thrown